# Fetch current birthdays after logging into facebook with pyhhon

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have decided to attempt to create a simple web scraper script in python. As a small challenge I decided to create a script which will be able to log me into facebook and fetch the current birthdays displayed in the side. I have managed to write a script which is able to log me into my facebook, however I have no idea how to fetch the birthdays displayed.

This is my scrypt.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from time import sleep 
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options 

usr = 'EMAIL'
pwd = 'PASSWORD'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install()) 
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/') 
print ("Opened facebook") 
sleep(1) 

username_box = driver.find_element_by_id('email') 
username_box.send_keys(usr) 
print ("Email Id entered") 
sleep(1) 

password_box = driver.find_element_by_id('pass') 
password_box.send_keys(pwd) 
print ("Password entered") 

login_box = driver.find_element_by_id('u_0_b') 
login_box.click() 

print ("Login Sucessfull")



print ("Fetched needed data") 
input('Press anything to quit') 
driver.quit() 
print("Finished")
```

This is my first time creating a script of this type. My assumption is that I am supposed to traverse through the children of the "jsc_c_3d" div element until I get to the displayed birthdays. Furthermore the id of this element changes everytime the page is refreshed. Can anyone tell me how this is done or if this is the right way that I should go on about solving this problem?
The div for the birthday after expecting elements:

```
<div class="" id="jsc_c_3d">
    <div class="j83agx80 cbu4d94t ew0dbk1b irj2b8pg">
        <div class="qzhwtbm6 knvmm38d"><span class="oi732d6d ik7dh3pa d2edcug0 qv66sw1b c1et5uql 
        a8c37x1j muag1w35 enqfppq2 jq4qci2q a3bd9o3v knj5qynh oo9gr5id hzawbc8m" dir="auto">
            <strong>Bobi Mitrevski</strong>
            and 
            <strong>Trajce Tusev</strong> have birthdays today.</span></div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you would need to traverse through the inner elements of `jsc_c_3d` to extract the birthdays that you want. However this whole `automated web-scraping` is a problem if the id value is dynamic, such that it changes on each occasion. In this case, text parsers such as `bs4` would do the job.

With the `bs4` approach you simply have to extract the relevant `div` tags from the `DOM` and then you can parse the data to obtain the required contents.

More generally, this problem is solvable using the `Facebook-API` which could be as simple as

```
import facebook

token = 'a token' # token omitted here, this is the same token when I use in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ 
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
args = {'fields' : 'birthday,name' }
friends = graph.get_object("me/friends",**args)
```